# c# field never assigned to will have default value of 0

Tags: c#

Just starting to work with classes. My int `age` isn't working with my property Age. It's always 0.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stuffers s = new Stuffers("Stuffy McStuff");
        }
    }

    class Stuffers
    {
        private int age;
        public int Age
        {
            get { return age; } set { value = age; }
        }
    }
}
```

Shows error:

> field age never assigned to, and will have default value of 0

---

original non-MCVE code

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stuffers s = new Stuffers("Stuffy McStuff");
            Console.WriteLine(s.GetName());

            Console.Write("{0}, what is your age?", s.GetName());
            s.Age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Stuffers s2 = new Stuffers("Leeroy");
            Console.WriteLine(s.GetAge());
        }
    }

    class Stuffers
    {
        private int age;
        private string name;
        public int Age
        {
            get { return age; } set { value = age; }
        }
        public Stuffers(string nameC)
        {
            name = nameC;
        }
        public string GetName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        public int GetAge()
        {
            return age;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Travis, thanks for the question. Unfortunately the stackoverflow community doesn't like answering to homework questions (I'm not the one who down voted btw =P). Just thought I'd let you know.

Comment: @Carlo How do you know this is homework? It doesn't seem like it to me at least.

Comment: It's not homework lol I'm just learning on my own and trying things. Thanks for the warning though lol

Comment: It looks like homework, but the question seems completely licit to me, it's a concrete error with a full code example to reproduce the behavior...

Comment: The question is asked many times and your particular variant looks like just typographical error. Since it is unlikely post will survive long I took liberty to edit code (which is generally not a god idea) and show what you should have posted as [MCVE] - there is no point to add extra code unrelated to problem you see.

Answer (score 5):

This is wrong:

```
public int Age
{
    get { return age; } set { value = age; }
}
```

It should be:

```
public int Age
{
    get { return age; } set { age = value; }
}
```

`value` is the new value that you are assigning. `age` is the housekeeping variable.

Alternatively, you can just do:

```
public int Age { get; set; }
```

without declaring `age`.

Also, `GetAge()` method seems redundant, and it is probably better to turn `GetName` into a get-only property:

```
class Stuffers
{
    public int Age
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Stuffers(string nameC)
    {
        Name = nameC;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting the age to the value

Change this

```
public int Age
{
    get { return age; } set { value = age; }
}
```

To this

```
public int Age
{
    get { return age; } set { age = value; }
}
```